# What is the proper way to add a required field to a post type?

Tags: custom-field, save-post

So I created a CPT that has a few required fields in a metabox. My metadata is being saved through the save_post hook but from I can find via my googlefu there is no way to stop the saving of the post from this hook.

Currently I'm stopping the submission of the form using javascript but I would also like to have a server side solution for this.

I guess I have a few questions:

1. Why was Wordpress developed so you can't stop the post submission?
2. What is the accepted way to do this?

Comment: Any `save_post` actions are done near the *end* of [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and [`wp_publish_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post). By the time the `save_post` actions run, the post has already been added or modified.

Comment: I'd just like to say that this was in fact a duplicate answer and that I did find my answer in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

In the `save_post` hook, When you are saving your post`s meta, Check initially for the required fields.
If it contains no value, You can straight away redirect user to the admin referrer with an appropriate error message.

You can also go for HTML5 required validation. That will be more efficient.

```
<input type="text" required>
```